# C++ super fast thread-safe rand function

Tags: c++, multithreading, optimization, random

```
void NetClass::Modulate(vector <synapse> & synapses )
{
    int size = synapses.size();
    int split = 200 * 0.5;

    for(int w=0; w < size; w++)
        if(synapses[w].active)
            synapses[w].rmod = ((rand_r(seedp) % 200 - split ) / 1000.0);
}
```

The function `rand_r(seedp)` is seriously bottle-necking my program. Specifically, its slowing me by 3X when run serialy, and 4.4X when run on 16 cores. `rand()` is not an option because its even worse. Is there anything I can do to streamline this? If it will make a difference, I think I can sustain a loss in terms of statistical randomness. Would pre-generating (before execution) a list of random numbers and then loading to the thread stacks be an option?

Comment: *You'll* need to tell *us* whether pre-generating all your random numbers is an option!

Comment: I wouldn't know, but did you check the boost random number generators? There is also hardware that generates random numbers, but that might not be faster. At any rate, since the core of the loop is just generating the random number, I would not really call it a 3x slow down... And at this point you will need to decide whether you want random numbers or not.

Comment: Also check out GSL (GNU scientific library) if GPL is OK for you.

Comment: @David This loop is only a very small part of the overall computation in my program. And having random numbers is essential.

Comment: @OliC I guess I was more asking whether its likely to speed things up under any conditions. Have you ever heard of it being done before etc.

Comment: You could always try to pre-generate a buffer at startup. It would have the benefit that you could precalculate the whole expression "((rand_r(seedp) % 200 - split ) / 1000.0)". The negative aspect of a look-up-table is the impact on the data cache.

Comment: @Matt: Of course, precalculating the sequence will reduce the runtime of your inner loop (unless you're memory-limited, in which case cache effects may become important).

Comment: @Matt, when evaluating performance do you switch on all optimizations and switch off all debug helping tools? Also, what happens if you save reference to `synapses[w]` before using it twice?

Comment: @Ville Interesting. Could you explain a little bit the difference between loading to a buffer and using a look-up-table in terms of the memory allocation and access?

Comment: @Oli In what way of being memory-limited? Do you mean running out of ram, or more like too much simultaneous memory access?

Comment: @Dialecticus save reference to?

Comment: @Matt: I mean limited in terms of memory bandwidth.  Having a large random-access lookup table will reduce your cache-hit rate, which more of your data accesses will be direct to main memory.  If the speed of your loop is limited by the CPU, you won't notice this.  But if it isn't, then you will.

Comment: `rand_r(seedp) % 200` is biased (unless your RAND_MAX just happens to be a multiple of 200, which it probably isn't). Not sure if this matters to your simulation.

Comment: @Oli If I'm accessing the lookup array linearly (iterating through it forwards) and in periodic 'chunks' as in the above loop, is it fairly likely that I won't have problems? (or at least that is a pretty good scenario right?)

Comment: @Matt: Yes, as you'd be iterating through your data array and the lookup array linearly, this should be pretty good from a cache point of view.

Comment: @Oli Alright, well it seems like the thing to do is give it a try. I've heard tell of a lot of rng's here and elsewhere, but no one seems capable of telling me definitively that anything is faster than rand_r() or rand(). Thanks for your help.

Comment: The thread-safety requirement is not important here. Just use thread-local state, like you do at the moment. This makes it significantly easier to find efficient implementations.

Comment: @Konrad do you know how I can implement `rand()` as thread-local?

Comment: @Matt Well that’s what `rand_r` does for you, isn’t it? The algorithm itself is just an LCG (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruence_generator#Parameters_in_common_use)) but that won’t help you if it’s too slow. Boost is probably your best option.

Comment: @Konrad do you have good reason to predict that boost will be capable of faster speeds?

Comment: @Matt No. But they do provide a wide variety of highly optimised random number generators so if there’s a fast generator, chances are that Boost will have it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is that `seedp` variable (and its memory location) is shared among several threads. Processor cores must synchronize their caches each time they access this ever changing value, which hampers performance. The solution is that all threads work with their own `seedp`, and so avoid cache synchronization.

Comment: great A, prob you also need to mention that maybe possibly false sharing can also be a problem if somebody uses seedp[N_THREADS]...

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl good comment. Small thread-specific variables (like `seedp` here) should live in thread's stack. Large structures should be separated in memory from structures of other threads. The code has to know about [cache size](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/12/08/9933836.aspx) to separate them properly.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on how good the statistical randomness needs to be. For high quality, the [Mersenne twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister), or its SIMD variant, is a good choice. You can generate and buffer a large block of pseudo-random numbers at a time, and each thread can have its own state vector. The [Park-Miller-Carta](http://www.firstpr.com.au/dsp/rand31/) PRNG is extremely simple - [these guys](http://www.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/wlangdon/ftp/public/papers/langdon_2009_CIGPU.pdf) even implemented it as a CUDA kernel.

Comment: HAHA! Eureka! The Park-Miller-Carta algorithm works like a charm. Speeds up serial execution by 24% and 16 core execution by 10X, yielding benefits up to the ~14th core. I highly recommend for anyone with similar needs to give this a try. Very easy to implement.

Comment: How can Park-Miller-Carta be faster than rand_r? Is there any chance that `seedp` in your code is shared between all threads? In that case cores must synchronize their caches in order to be able to access the same memory location, and that takes time. Give each thread its own `seedp` and see what happens.

Comment: @Dialecticus I meant to post the following a long time ago. Yes, you are exactly right. The problem was that I did not have a seperate seedp for each thread. I changed that and the speed increased to at least as good as the PMC generator mentioned above (I can't actually remember the exact difference). Everyone please disregard my earlier comment; I would strongly recommend using `rand_r` over PMC.

Comment: @Dialecticus, I feel like your comment should be posted as an answer, and that answer accepted.

Comment: @Dialecticus - I am extremely skeptical that, given the call overhead of `rand_r` alone, it would beat an aggressively inlined PMC with different (seed) contexts - e.g., per thread. And neither would come close to Marsaglia's extremely efficient [xorshift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift), which has superior statistical properties as well.

Comment: Sorry, I've read your comment several times, but not exactly sure what you're saying and what should my answer be. Could you dumb it down a notch for me?

Comment: Alright, I think I understand. You are saying PMC is faster than rand_r, and I asked how can it be faster, and you are now asserting that it is in fact faster. The thing is, we are not talking about the same thing. You were comparing two algorithms, and I was trying to unravel a problem. Maybe I should have asked "how can it be THAT faster" to be clearer.

Answer (score 5):

Marsaglia's [xor-shift generator](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v08/i14/paper) is the probably fastest "reasonable quality" generator that you can use. It does not quite have the same "quality" as MT19937 or WELL, but honestly these differences are academic sophistries.
For all real, practical uses, there is no observable difference, except 1-2 orders of magnitude difference in execution speed, and 3 orders of magnitude of difference in memory consumption.

The xor-shift generator is also naturally thread-safe (in the sense that it will produce non-deterministic, pseudorandom results, and it will not crash) without anything special, and it can be trivially made thread-safe in another sense (in the sense that it will generate per-thread independent, deterministic, pseudorandom numbers) by having one instance per thread.
It could also be made threadsafe in yet another sense (generate a deterministic, pseudorandom sequence handed out to threads as they come) using atomic compare-exchange, but I don't think that's very useful.

The only three notable issues with the xor-shift generator are:

- It is not k-distributed for up to 623 dimensions, but honestly who cares. I can't think in more than 4 dimensions (and even that's a lie!), and can't imagine many applications where more than 10 or 20 dimensions could possibly matter. That would have to be some quite esoteric simulation.
- It passes most, but not ever pedantic statistic test. Again, who cares. Most people use a random generator that does not even pass a single test and never notice.
- A zero seed will produce a zero sequence. This is trivially fixed by adding a non-zero constant to one of the temporaries (I wonder why Marsaglia never thought of that?). Having said that, MT19937 also behaves extremely badly given a zero seed, and does not recover nearly as well.

Comment: Really?  You can't think of ever needing more than 10 or 20 dimensions?  How many questions were on the last poll or survey you took?  How many possibly physically important variables do you think go into a process needing simulation (fluid mechanics, driving, etc)

Comment: @McBeth: Fluid simulation is one of the very few applications where such things may really matter. Also note that I am not saying I can't think of ever needing more than 10 or 20 dimensions. I said I can't think of needing more than 10 or 20 dimensions which are randomized and need to have no pattern between the dimensions. Note that the OP's code contains a `% 200`, so much for patterns. If you really need 500 or 600 provably independently distributed dimensions in your simulation, fine, xor-shift is not what you want, use WELL. But I'm saying that most people don't _really_ need this.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at `Boost`: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_random.html
It has a number of options which vary in complexity (= speed) and randomness (cycle length).

If you don't need maximum randomness, you might get away with a simple Mersenne Twister.

Comment: To clarify: Neither of these is more random than the other.  They both have zero randomness.

Comment: Randomness as used for simulations (uncorrelated with the actual process): yes.
Randomness as required for cryptography: no.

Answer (score 1):

do you absolutely need to have 1 shared random?

I had a similar contention problem a while ago, the solution that worked best for me was to create a new Random class (I was working in C#) for each thread. they're dead cheap anyway.

If you seed them properly to make sure you don't create duplicate seeds you should be fine. Then you won't have shared state so you don't need to use the threadsafe function.

Regards GJ

Comment: @gjvdkamp how do I create a random class and ensure that the randomization is indeed kept to seperate threads. I was under the impression that this could not be done with rand().

Comment: I'm afraid I'm going to have to leave that to the c++ people in this thread, my c++ and library knowledge is very limited. If rand is just a function you'd need to replace that with a RNG that is implemented as a class, I'm sure there are plenty.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you don't have to call it in every iteration? you could initialize an array of pre-randomized elements and make successive use of it...

Answer (score -5):

I think you can use OpenMP for paralleling like this:

```
#pragma omp parallel
for(int w=0; w < size; w++)
```