# Thread safe random numbers

Tags: c++

I tried to implement "Monte Carlo" algorithm in parallel manner, so I need to use a thread safe version of a random number generator.
I searched a lot and finally found 
`int qrand ()`
which is a Thread-safe version of the standard C++ `rand()` function, (defined in `<cstdlib>` and `<stdlib.h>`). When I use it, VS fired "identifier not found" error.

I use MS visual studio'10 and wrote my code in C++ using OMP.

Any help?

Comment: You might be interested in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8285067/c-super-fast-thread-safe-rand-function

Comment: I think `qrand` is part of Qt, not standard C++. Maybe you're looking for `rand_r`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7114482/5987 particularly the part about concurrency.

Comment: If you're using MSVC, the standard C/C++ `rand()` *is* threadsafe since the seed is stored in TLS (at least since VS2005), not sure it's the best solution though since the distribution of `rand()` isn't very random...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`boost::random` has a number of generators which are objects.  The
simplest solution would be to simply use a distinct generator for each
thread.

Answer (score 6):

For C++ use the standard `<random>` library. As James Kanze suggests, a different generator for each thread would probably be best, and they're not difficult to make:

```
#include <random>

std::mt19937 make_seeded_engine() {
    std::random_device r;
    std::seed_seq seed{r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r()};
    return std::mt19937(seed);
}

std::async([](){
    auto rand = std::bind(std::uniform_real_distribution<>(),
                          make_seeded_engine());
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        rand();
});
```

I'm just using `std::async()` to show that the generator is created in the thread. MSVC 10 doesn't have `std::async()` I don't think, but it does have `<random>`, so you'll do the same thing just using whatever threading library you're already using.