# Faster twister engine? mt19937_16?

Tags: c++, c++11, random

I'm doing some scientific computing and I noticed that a large part of my code is spent coming up with random numbers.

I generate my numbers using the twister engine `mt19937`, I noticed there was also a slower `_64` version, does anybody know the magic numbers to enter into the template to make a hopefully faster `_16` version?

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine

Somebody might ask, why not use xorshf96 or something else lame. I like the spectral properties of the twist engine.

Comment: Just to confirm, you are okay with the (more) limited range that a sixteen-bit wide random number would give you.

Comment: Have you tried Well512 (for 32 bit code) or Well1024 (for 64 bit code)? They're simpler than MT, but produce similar quality output.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: WELL doesn't just produce similar quality output, it produces better output (... and is faster). Mikhail: Instead of doing a _16 version, is there a hindrance to splitting the result in two? That'll likely be faster, and under the assumption that the bits are sufficiently "random", it shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Just do what I do: generate them in advance, and #include the generated file. Hey-presto, fast random numbers!  ;p

Comment: I hope you have separate engines for each thread. Otherwise there will be too much of [cache synchronization](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8285067/395718).

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_random/reference.html#boost_random.reference.generators enjoy :)

Comment: Mersenne Twister isn't really so high-quality to justify its slowness. Use an algorithm like Marsaglia's MWC. Check out my http://github.com/lcrocker/ojrandlib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this [SFMT library](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/SFMT/) could be of some use for you.