# C++ thread-safe uniform distribution random number generation

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, openmp, prng

I have a loop.
Inside the loop, in each iteration, I need to draw a number from U[0,1].
How can I use openmp, and also make sure that the random number generating process is not contaminated?

I got suggestion that I need a thread-safe random number generator, which may or may not be the solution to my problem.

My question is very related to another one, with a slight difference that I want to draw from a coninuum U[0,1]. Additionally, I don't know how to seed generator by thread, can someone please write a line of code?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use a different random number generator per thread?

Comment: Can you do that in the case of openmp?

Comment: @MarkRansom I rephrased my question. I think what I need is thread-safe generation of random numbers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I generate thread-safe uniform random numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21237905/how-do-i-generate-thread-safe-uniform-random-numbers)

Comment: @MikeMB, Yes my question is very related to another one, with a slight difference that I want to draw from a coninuum U[0,1]. Additionally, I don't know how to seed generator by thread.

Comment: To get a uniform distribution in [0, 1], you can simply modify the solution for integers.  That is, generate an integer in the range `[0, large_int]`, then convert to your preferred floating type and divide by `large_int`, e.g. `double random_float = (double) random_int / large_int`.

Comment: @JeffIrwin: Why so complicated? There is already a random number generator for floating point numbers in the standard library.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on the already [mentioned solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21237905/how-do-i-generate-thread-safe-uniform-random-numbers), here is a version adapted to your specific needs:

```
double doubleRand(double min, double max) {
    thread_local std::mt19937 generator(std::random_device{}());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(min, max);
    return distribution(generator);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There was already a topic for that in SO:
[How do I generate thread-safe uniform random numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21237905/how-do-i-generate-thread-safe-uniform-random-numbers)

Basically, the solution is to use different random generator for each thread, and to seed each one with thread specific data( in this case - the thread id ).

Comment: I did check that one. My situation is very similar but slightly different. I would like to draw from a continuum, i.e. U[0,1]. I honestly don't know how to modify that code.

Comment: Additionally, how do I seed the generator and where do I seed the generator?