# C++ - Templated Uniform Distribution?

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, uniform-distribution

Currently I am overloading this function to generate a random number:

```
float GetRand(float lower, float upper) {                                                                                                                                                      
    std::random_device rd;                                                                                                                                                                    
    std::mt19937_64 mt(rd());                                                                                                                                                                 
    std::uniform_real_distribution<float> dist(lower,upper);                                                                                                                                  
    return dist(mt);                                                                                                                                                                            
}                                                                                                                                                                                              

int GetRand(int lower, int upper) {                                                                                                                                                            
    std::random_device rd;                                                                                                                                                                    
    std::mt19937_64 mt(rd());                                                                                                                                                                 
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(lower,upper);                                                                                                                                     
    return dist(mt);                                                                                                                                                                          
}
```

Is it possible to do this with a template? I don't know how I could template the distribution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can unify both overloadings of `GetRand` as a function template.

First of all, please note that the effect of [**`std::uniform_real_distribution<T>`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution) is undefined if `T` is not one of `float`, `double` and `long double`.
For instance, *29.6.1.1 General requirements [rand.req.genl]* in C++ standard draft n4687 states:

> Throughout this subclause **29.6**, the effect of instantiating a template:
>
> ...
>
> d) that has a template type parameter named **RealType** is undefined unless the corresponding template
>   argument is cv-unqualified and is one of **float**, **double**, or **long double**.

In addition, ***29.6***.8.2.2 Class template uniform_real_distribution [rand.dist.uni.real] describes `std::uniform_real_distribution` with the template type parameter **`RealType`** and therefore `std::uniform_real_distribution<int>` is undefined:

> ```
> template<class RealType = double>
> class uniform_real_distribution {
>     ...
> };
> ```

Also, similar restriction exists for [**`std::uniform_int_distribution<T>`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution).
Thus we need to toggle the distribution type between `std::uniform_real_distribution<T>` and `std::uniform_int_distribution<T>` depending on `T`.

---

We can check the above restrictions using `std::is_floating_point` and `std::is_integral` and make the following switch:

```
#include <random>
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
using uniform_distribution = 
typename std::conditional<
    std::is_floating_point<T>::value,
    std::uniform_real_distribution<T>,
    typename std::conditional<
        std::is_integral<T>::value,
        std::uniform_int_distribution<T>,
        void
    >::type
>::type;
```

Then two overloadings of `GetRand` can be unified to the following function template.
Here I also avoid recursive construction of `std::mt19937_64` and make the function thread-safe applying the accepted answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21237905/how-do-i-generate-thread-safe-uniform-random-numbers).

```
template <class T>
T GetRand(T lower, T upper)
{
    static thread_local std::mt19937_64 mt(std::random_device{}());
    uniform_distribution<T> dist(lower,upper);

    return dist(mt);
}
```

---

Finally, the caller side would be as follows:

[**DEMO**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/CpIeX7Gwki5aWKnt)

```
auto i = GetRand<int>   (0, 1); // 0 or 1
auto f = GetRand<float> (0, 1); // [0, 1)
auto d = GetRand<double>(0, 1); // [0, 1)
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: Nifty trick indeed. Thank you!