# password generator issue at the moment to convert vector to string

Tags: c++

I am trying to generate my key random and joining a few hyphen after the key , but however when I try to do this I got `no suitable user-defined conversion from "std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string>>" to "std::string"` on the other hand how can I include srand(time(NULL)); instead of declaring them every time on main . is will possible to include it on my random function?

```c
typedef unsigned int uint;

std::string randomString(uint length, std::string string){
    std::vector<uint> indexesOfRandomChars(length); // array of random values that will be used to iterate through random indexes of 'charIndex'
    for (uint i = 0; i < length; ++i) // assigns a random number to each index of "indexesOfRandomChars"
        indexesOfRandomChars[i] = rand() % string.length();

    std::string key = ""; // random string that will be returned by this function
    for (uint i = 0; i < length; ++i)// appends a random amount of random characters to "randomString"
    {
        key += string[indexesOfRandomChars[i]];
    }
    return key;
}
```

```c
int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    std::vector<std::string> t{ reverse.ascii_lowercase() , reverse.ascii_uppercase() , reverse.digits() , reverse.punctuation() };
    std::cout << reverse.join(randomString(15, t), "--") << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Moving `srand(time(NULL));` in your function would give you the same seed for all your iterations, thus you endup with the same number at each call of `rand()`.

Comment: What is `randomString(15, t)` trying to achieve? Your question mentions a singular key (a string?), but you're passing a vector of strings.

Comment: t is a long string which contains abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz--ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ--0123456789--!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`  , but I want to send to my t data to in this way

Comment: Well apparently, it's a vector of 4 strings, not a single long string. You can just do `std::string t = reverse.ascii_lowercase() + reverse.ascii_uppercase() + ...` to get a long string.

Comment: sure, but join is a std::vector<std::string> that's why t needs to be a vector , but how can I send them t to random function as vector?

Comment: `join` is a function which... takes an std::vector<std::string>? If I understand correctly, you're trying to pass each string in the vector `t` (`reverse.ascii_lowercase()`, `reverse.ascii_uppercase()`, etc) into `randomString`. If so, one quick way would be to iterate through and calling `randomString` on each element of `t`, pushing results into a second vector, then joining the second vector.

Comment: yes that one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already suggested in comments, the second argument of `randomString` is `std::string` but you are passing `std::vector<std::string> t` to it.
Thus you get the current compilation error.
For instance, if the type of the first argument of `join` is `std::vector<std::string>`, the caller side of `randomString` should be as follows:

```
std::vector<std::string> t{
    randomString(15, reverse.ascii_lowercase()),
    randomString(15, reverse.ascii_uppercase()),
    randomString( 5, reverse.digits()),
    randomString( 5, reverse.punctuation()) };

std::cout << reverse.join(t, "--") << std::endl;
```

---

Next,

> how can I include srand(time(NULL)); instead of declaring them every time on main

In C++, the life time of static local variables starts when the function is called and ends when the program ends.
Therefore, `srand(time(NULL))` in the following `setSeed` is called only once through the run-time and in this way you can include `srand(time(NULL))` in the `randomString` instead of declaring them in the main function.
(Please note that `srand` is in effect globally and if you are calling `rand()` in other functions with different purposes then you also need to call this `setSeed` in these functions. Then, in this case, the main function seems to be the most appropriate point to call `srand`.)

[**Live Demo**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/V53FsPNHI5whVV33)

```
void setSeed()
{
    static bool set = false;
    
    if(!set)
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        set = true;
    }
}

std::string randomString(uint length, std::string string)
{
    setSeed(); // I added this line.
    
    std::vector<uint> indexesOfRandomChars(length); // array of random values that will be used to iterate through random indexes of 'charIndex'
    for (uint i = 0; i < length; ++i) // assigns a random number to each index of "indexesOfRandomChars"
        indexesOfRandomChars[i] = rand() % string.length();

    std::string key = ""; // random string that will be returned by this function
    for (uint i = 0; i < length; ++i)// appends a random amount of random characters to "randomString"
    {
        key += string[indexesOfRandomChars[i]];
    }
    return key;
}
```

---

BTW, although `rand()` should be usually implemented using something better LCG,
but, for instance as noted in C++ standard draft n4687, the algorithm used in `rand()` is completely compiler implementation defined:

> **29.6.9 Low-quality random number generation [c.math.rand]**
>
> ```
> int rand();
> void srand(unsigned int seed);
> ```
>
> ... **rand’s underlying algorithm is unspecified**. Use of rand therefore continues to be non-portable, with unpredictable and oft-questionable quality and performance.

Fortunately, in C++11 and over, we can use `<random>` to generate a guaranteed quality randomness.
Thus I recommend you to use them as follows.
Here I also avoid recursive construction of `std::minstd_rand` and make the function thread-safe applying the accepted answer in [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21237905/how-do-i-generate-thread-safe-uniform-random-numbers).
If you need more high-quality randomness, you can use `std::mt19937` instead of `std::minstd_rand`:

[**Live Demo**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/eFbHOPChOmFXtwj5)

```
#include <random>

std::string randomString(
    std::size_t length,
    const std::string& str)
{
    static thread_local std::minstd_rand gen(std::random_device{}());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<std::size_t> dist(0, str.length()-1);
    
    std::string ret;
    ret.reserve(length);
    
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i){
        ret.push_back(str[dist(gen)]);
    }
    
    return ret;
}
```